# psconfig stops at C2WTS service install for an hour before moving on and finishing properly

Tags: 2016, psconfig

We have 2 SharePoint 2016 on-prem farms; each has 2 front ends and 2 app servers. One farm is production and the other is a hot backup. For the past few years, 6 of the 8 servers would pause for about 3 minutes at the step in psconfig where it is working on the C2WTS update. The 2 production front ends took 15 minutes. Curious, but ok. We couldn't find anything to indicate the problem.
However, last patch cycle, the 2 front ends took an hour each before finishing! Nothing in any logs. Just an hour of time between "bootstrap" and "continuing installation" in the Upgrade log. No entries in event viewer. The CPU indicator in Task Manager slowly ticked up and down. These servers were created at the same time by the same team. They are as identical as we can tell.
Has anyone heard of anything like this? Can you give me any clues to look for?

Comment: Are you using the GUI/Wizard to patch SharePoint? Have you tried to patch with the help of any PowerShell script that stops certain services while patching?

Comment: We use PowerShell. This is the command: PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services - install